# Are there any MVP Frameworks projects out there?

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

MVC is used a number of popular frameworks. To name just a few, Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC, Monorail, Spring MVC.

Are there any equivalent frameworks using any variant of MVP?

Most of the examples I've found online seem to be custom implementations of the pattern rather than reusable frameworks.

Suggestions need not be specific to any particular programming language, my interest is mostly academic.

Comment: The reason I asked about this was I was researching User Interface Patterns in preparation for a Lightning Talk presentation at a local user group. I have since written up the talk in the form of a blog:

http://gregmalcolm.com/archive/2009/07/14/user-interface-patterns.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/) is really an MVP framework, in spite of the name.

Comment: Ah, I think I've seen that mentioned before somewhere, but overlooked it because of the name. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 1):

I GWT uses MVP Pattern. See [this](http://code.google.com/events/io/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) video.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an "MVP Bundle" in Web Client Software Factory (WCSF) 2.0.

Comment: Thanks to "Jeronimo" who posted on my blog for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm maintaining [Claymore](http://claymore.codeplex.com/) an MVP framework for Winform, ASP.NET et Compact Framework.